# Prevent Android request from using cellular data

Tags: android, okhttp

We're making a number of large uploads from an Android app. We want to force these to use WiFi and never use cellular so we don't waste the user's cellular data plan.

Currently we're checking connection status using ConnectivityManager, and ensuring they connected to WiFi. This approach seems to have stopped working on Android 7, as sometimes even when WiFi is connected, the OS decides to send the requests over cellular.

On iOS we can use allowsCellularAccess=false to explicitly prevent this.

Is there a way on Android to require a request to use WiFi? Ideally at the request level, not the entire app. We don't want to limit the entire app to WiFi, just the large uploads.

We're using OkHttpRequest, but willing to use another lib if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html)

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            // make large uploads here
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, " connected to WIFI");
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, " Connected to Mobile");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " No connection");
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks. We were using getAllNetworkInfo and checking for Wifi (assuming it would use it if available). getActiveNetworkInfo should fix this. Thanks!